# Java: Regex replacement based on match group contents

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string which takes the form (stripped down):

```
{
    headers : {
        root : function () { return context('headers'); },
        types : function () { return context('headers/types'); },
        groups : function () { return context('headers/groups'); },
    },
    sidebar : {
        remove : function () { return contextUrl('sidebars/remove/'); }
    },
    footer : {
        root : function () { return contextUrl('footer'); }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a regex that will replace all the function calls with the string that lies between the context function inside it.

Example: my desired output based on the above input is:

```
{
    headers : {
        root : 'headers',
        types : 'headers/types',
        groups : 'headers/groups',
    },
    sidebar : {
        remove : 'sidebars/remove/'
    },
    footer : {
        root : 'footer'
    }
}
```

I haven't written a regex which replaces a group with the match of another group before. I'm assuming that this couldn't be done using one regex?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I realise I'm probably butchering regex for this purpose.. But considered it the best approach considering the other alternatives (I could think of):

1) The input string is valid JavaScript, therefore I could run it through java's scripting engine and let engine do the work. This would mean I'd need to add self invoking tags to each of the function calls, forging them to invoke and return the value though - All very messy

2) String replacement - Chain a few string replacement calls to strip away the function altogether - Very Messy

3) Regex - Which led me to this post

If there's a different way to achieve this I'm all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This regex creates the desired output for me

```
String s = "{\n"
        + "    headers : {\n"
        + "      root : function () { return context('headers'); },\n"
        + "      types : function () { return context('headers/types'); },\n"
        + "      groups : function () { return context('headers/groups'); },\n"
        + "    },\n"
        + "    sidebar : {\n"
        + "        remove : function () { return contextUrl('sidebars/remove/'); }\n"
        + "    },\n"
        + "    footer : {\n"
        + "        root : function () { return contextUrl('footer'); }\n"
        + "    }\n" + "}";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("function\\s+\\(.*\\)\\s+\\{\\s+return\\s+[A-Za-z]+\\(('[A-Za-z\\s/]+')\\)\\s*;\\s+\\}", "$1"));
```

Edit: note that slight changes to the syntax of the given String will lead to wrong results.

Comment: You could also go with a simpler, more strict (less forgiving) version: `"function \\(\\) \\{ return context(?:Url)?\\(('[^']*')\\); \\}"`

Comment: @Andreas Yeah that´s true, but i tried to be a bit more forgiving by also including function parameter and multiple whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did strip down the example input string. The full version does have function arguments, so appreciate the foresight for this.

Answer (score 0):

Regex probably is not best tool for that, but you can try with:

```
(?<=:\s)function\s*\(\)\s\{[^(]+\(('[^']+')\);\s\}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rY5xE3/2)

you can use [`replaceAll("$1")`](https://ideone.com/itNY2V).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there better methods you can think to achieve this?